# PHP - MYSQL - Display Pages by id from One php file

Tags: php

I have a problem to do the code work...I don't know why its not working...I want to display from the database title and many other by id...The name of the file is view.php...If I want to show id 1 then I type on url view.php?id=1 or id 2 view.php?id=2...here is my code please help me out...

```
<?php
$getid = $_GET["id"];

$dbuser = 'user';
$userpass = 'pass';
$database = 'db';

error_reporting(0);
$con = mysql_connect("localhost",$dbuser,$userpass);
if(!$con){die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db($database, $con);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');


$query = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,description FROM player WHERE id = '$getid'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $id = $result['id'];
    $title = $result['title'];
    $description = $result['description'];
    echo 'ID: '.$id.'<br />Title: '.$title.'<br />Description: '.$description;
}else{
    echo 'Error';
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: I have made a database I add the url and its echo Error...and not that I want

Comment: what does the error say

Comment: Perhaps read the exception that occurs? How can you post a question without the problem?

Comment: Its Echo the else and not the if...I have on else echo 'Error' that it does

Comment: change mysql_query(...); to mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error()); and tell us the error please

Comment: Wrap your query execution with a `try`. Catch and print/log any exceptions

Comment: well you say: mysql_num_rows($query), but you never say how much it should be, so it always goes to else

Comment: @KoenHoeijmakers so what have I to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
```

to this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query) >= 1){
```

keep in mind that you've got to have things in your database with the ID that you give,

 or it will just go to else again.

(mysql_num_rows returns FALSE or an integer with the amount of rows, and since the if statement didnt check for an integer but for true, it always went down the ELSE path)

[Source: PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Comment: @gibsonman507 mysql_num_rows returns FALSE or an integer with the amount of rows, and since the if statement didnt check for an integer but for true, it always was to go to the ELSE

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,description FROM player WHERE id = '$getid'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count != 0){
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $id = $result['id'];
        $title = $result['title'];
        $description = $result['description'];
        echo 'ID: '.$id.'<br />Title: '.$title.'<br />Description: '.$description;
    }
}else{
    echo 'Error';
}
?>
```